# How to enable Solr's HTTP and HTTPS ports simultaneously

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I have configured SSL for Solr using following tutorial (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/enabling-ssl.html) and it is accepting HTTPS connections. I want to open a separate port for HTTP now so that Solr can receive HTTP and HTTPS requests at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIS Solr does not support both HTTP and HTTPS at the same time. You can only use one of them at a time.

Reference:

Check comment by Shalin in below post
[here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL)

Check last comment by Shawn in below post
[here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Using-HTTP-and-HTTPS-at-the-same-time-td4345502.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Jetty.XML,
Uncomment the connector for HTTPS

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
          <Set name="keyStore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/solrtest.keystore</Set>
          <Set name="keyStorePassword">secret</Set>
          <Set name="needClientAuth"><SystemProperty name="jetty.ssl.clientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
      <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.ssl.port" default="8983"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: Also, One can update the port accordingly. However, Both HTTP & HTTPS can't be enabled simultaneously from this change.